# How to collect elements in a RDD by batches

Tags: pyspark, rdd, batch-processing

I have a pyspark RDD which has ~2 million elements. I cannot collect them all at once, because it causes an `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

How can I collect them in batches?

This is a potential solution, but I suspect there is better: collect a batch (using `take`, https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.take.html#pyspark.RDD.take), then remove all elements from the RDD in that batch (using `filter`, https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.filter.html#pyspark.RDD.filter, but I suspect there is a better way), reiterate until no elements are collected.

Comment: `.collect()` is not meant to be used beyond experimenting and testing. What is your use case ? Data should be read, processed and written in parallel by executors. You can use the resulting data elsewhere if needed.

Comment: The use case is to write it to a database.

Comment: Why is '.collect()' not meant to be used beyond experimenting and testing? What is the philosophy beyond it? Are there any articles/blogs about its best practices?

Comment: Spark can write to databases (Hive, JDBC or whatever) in parallel. There is no need for collect. Spark is best used for large scale parallelism. When using collect, you're pulling all the data into a single node killing all parallelism, which a simple Python script could easily overperform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure its a good solution, but you can zip your rdd with an index, and then filter on that index to collect the items in batches:

```
big_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([str(i) for i in range(0, 100)])
big_rdd_with_index = big_rdd.zipWithIndex()
batch_size = 10
batches = []
for i in range(0, 100, batch_size):
  batches.append(big_rdd_with_index.filter(lambda element: i <= element[1] < i + batch_size).map(lambda element: element[0]).collect())
for l in batches:
  print(l)
```

Output:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19']
['20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29']
['30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39']
['40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49']
['50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59']
['60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69']
['70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79']
['80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89']
['90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99']
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Comment: It needs to be evaluated performance and memory-wise, but I like this idea